# Fetch does not let Express.js/Node.js render a response from server-side to an EJS template in client-side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

**Purpose:** Reading input (data) from the client-side, sending the data to the server-side (Node.js/Express.js), modifying the data on the server-side, and sending the modified data back to the client-side (EJS template)

**Problem:** When I use fetch() with the method set to POST, I can send data to the server-side, but I cannot render the modified data back to the client-side. However, if I use the HTML form directly with the method set to POST, I can achieve the goal (the purpose). However, I need to POST with fetch().

**Research:**
To narrow down the problem and especially check on the server-side code, I tried the following code without fetch(): I take the user's name from the input and send it to the server-side. On the server-side, I add a Hello and then return "Hello first_name last_name!" to an EJS variable named word:

The HTML form (in an ejs template):

```
<form action="/users" id="example-form" method="POST">
    <label for="first-name">
        <strong>First Name:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first-name">
    </label>

    <label for="last-name">
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last-name">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Create new user">
</form>

<br><hr><br>
<% var word %>
<h2><%= word %></h2>
```

The server-side code is:

```
//app.use(express.json())

app.post('/users', (req,res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
     
    res.render('index5',
    {
        word: `Hello ${req.body.first_name} ${req.body.last_name}!`
    })
    
})
```

I commented out

```
//app.use(express.json())
```

and the code works without it.

Now, I remove method = "POST" from the HTML code. The following code is adopted from [Simon Plenderleith's website](https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/):

HTML code:

```
   <form action="/users" id="example-form">
        <label for="first-name">
            <strong>First Name:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first-name">
        </label>
    
        <label for="last-name">
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last-name">
        </label>
    
        <input type="submit" value="Create new user">
    </form>
```

I add the following to this HTML code and save them all in index5.ejs:

```
<br><hr><br>
<% var word %>
<h2><%= word %></h2>
```

I add the following JavaScript code from [Simon Plenderleith's website](https://simonplend.com/how-to-use-fetch-to-post-form-data-as-json-to-your-api/) to index5.ejs:

```
  async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
        const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
        const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);

        const fetchOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
            body: formDataJsonString,
        };

        const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorMessage = await response.text();
            throw new Error(errorMessage);
        }

        return response.json();
    }


    async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const form = event.currentTarget;
        const url = form.action;

        try {
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData });

            console.log({ responseData });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    const exampleForm = document.getElementById("example-form");
    exampleForm.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);

</script>
```

This gives the following error message in the console (client-side Chrome dev tool):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Also, in the console in the client-side we see we have received an empty object:

```
{}
```

We still do not see any Hello first_name last_name! (e.g. Hello John Smith!) on the client-side! So the code also failed to render back those strings to the client-side (index5.ejs)

In the above-given server code, I remove the comment // from app.use(express.json())

So, this is now the code on the server-side:

```
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/users', (req,res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
     
    res.render('index5',
    {
        word: `Hello ${req.body.first_name} ${req.body.last_name}!`
    })
    
})
```

Now, we try John Smith again:

This time we have an improvement and we get this object in the console on the server-side:

```
{ first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith' }
```

We do not see Hello John Smith! on the client-side, so the server-side code fails to render it to the ejs variable word, when we use fetch() with the method set to POST. Remember, the server-side code worked with HTML form, when method = "POST" was set in the  tag.

Also, I still get this error message in the console on the client-side (Chrome dev tool):

```
(index):68 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Using the Chrome dev tool, this error can be traced back to the following line of code in the above-given JavaScript code:

```
 console.error(error);
```

Using Chrome dev tool under Networking/Fetch/XHR/Payload, I see the following:

```
{first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith"}
first_name: "John"
last_name: "Smith"
```

Seemingly, the above code with fetch() is successful in sending the data to the server-side but the following part of the server-side code fails:

```
 res.render('index5',
    {
        word: `Hello ${req.body.first_name} ${req.body.last_name}!`
    })
```

Clearly, I have to find a better understanding of how the data goes back and forth between the client-side and the server-side. While I continue working on this, I appreciate it if you could help me find out what I am missing and if you could suggest a quick fix for the above-given code.

Best regards,

Eric

**Update May 4, 2022**

If I change

```
return response.json()
```

in the JavaScript code (client-side) to

```
return response
```

then the error message in the console (client-side) disappears.This, however, does not solve the problem at hand: why with a regular form, node.js/express.js can render to an ejs template but with fetch() it cannot.

Comment: fetch() is used to load data in the background. It will not make the browser navigate to the result. And calling `response.json()` when you're sending back HTML not JSON will cause the infamous parsing error, you're trying to parse HTML as if it were JSON.

Comment: If you have a regular form and you just want to POST its contents, don't bother with any JS. Just use the form as-is. There's no need to handle the submit event, or convert to JSON or use fetch() or any of that.

Comment: Here's example code for loading JSON with a bunch of users and adding them to the already loaded page: https://jsfiddle.net/ea1d8m2v/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. There are reasons that I have to accomplish this task with fetch(), not a regular form. I left them out to avoid distraction from the problem at hand. I gave the example of working code with regular form, to narrow down where the problem is, in this case, it is the fetch() block.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with this: I've told you how fetch() works, it can either do what you want or it can't. You're clearly a beginner, and this sounds more and more like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. You need to tell us what your actual goal is, or we will be wasting a lot of time.

Comment: `node.js/express.js can render to an ejs template but with fetch() it cannot.` How the request is started doesn't matter to the server; node will render the template either way. The difference is that clicking a link or submitting a form will make the browser navigate to the result while fetch() doesn't. That is not a problem you can solve because fetch() is used for specific purposes. What you could do is take the HTML it loads, then insert it into the DOM for instance. There are downsides to this. Right now we need to know what "tasks" you have to "accomplish"

Comment: The bottom line is this: if the data you want to POST cannot be posted with a regular form, then you can for instance 1. POST with fetch 2. reply with "success" or similar 3. redirect to a different page on the client-side. What I'm saying is that this is most likely a trivial problem which has a bunch of existing solutions.